# how to disable the screen on data load?

Tags: ajax, user-interface

we are trying to show a **loading** image while the data is loading from the database. we are using AJAX calls for retrieving the data. Currently we are able to display that image. what we need now is to disable the entire screen and show only the **loading** image while the data is loading.

is there any ready made solution to this??? i hope there are lot of frameworks which can do this.
Please provide relevant pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: entire screen means? you want the computer to freeze? :)

Comment: i mean the entire, browser screen should be disabled. just like a modal popup.

Comment: disabled means??? you dont show anything other than the image right? then what do you want to disable? do u have a sample screengrab?

Comment: can you visit this link http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/11/01/usability-tips-visualizing-ajax-requests.aspx
Under Disable UI elements during Ajax request please see the image. i want the parent window inaccessible while the image is getting displayed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by creating a div(transparent) and overlayed above all the elements.

```
   var freezeDiv = document.createElement("div");
   freezeDiv.id = "freezeDiv";
   freezeDiv.style.cssText = "position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:" + screen.width + "px; height:" + screen.height + "px; background-color: #000000; opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)";    
   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(freezeDiv );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ramesh. that code really helped me to disable the below screen. Now i want to display an DIV on top of the everything, saying Loading is in progress and an image which hints at loading. Any thoughts how we can do this?
i tried, but the image is getting displayed below the trasparent thing.
Thanks

Comment: I think you have added the progress label & image on the parent page (or a container).. Just add this items into the 'freezeDiv' div container, and center it... it ll work as expected...